# unable to preserve DropDownList.SelectedValue after disabling/re-enabling

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following `ASP:DropDownList` on my aspx page:

```
<label>OT Code No.</label>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlOvertimeCode" class="form-control" TabIndex="1"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Which renders as the following in HTML:

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ddlOvertimeCode" id="MainContentPlaceHolder_ddlOvertimeCode" tabindex="1" class="form-control">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">-Select-</option>
    <option value="1">1 - 10B PLES</option>
    <option value="2">2 - Investigation</option>
    <option value="3">3 - Arrest</option>
    <option value="4">4 - Misc</option>
    <option value="5">5 - EWW</option>
    <option value="6">6 - Holiday</option>
    <option value="7">7 - In-Lieu Holiday</option>
</select>
```

When submitted the form, I disable the `DropDownList` using the following code in my .cs file

```
ddlOvertimeCode.Attributes.Add("disabled", null);
```

I tried other methods of disabling the `dropdownlist`, however all of them would either override the bootstrap styling of the list or leave the dropdownlist able to be changed despite being grayed-out and ReadOnly.  Adding the `disabled` attribute is the only way I could find to gray-out the box while leaving it's styling intact.

the problem arrises when the user withdraws the form, making it editable again, and the code re-enables the `dropdownlist` using the same method:

```
ddlOvertimeCode.Attributes.Remove("disabled");
```

removing the `disabled` attribute resets the `dropdownlist` and leaves me unable to alter `DropDownList.SelectedValue` from the codebehind.

I need a method of graying out the DropDownList and disabling it from the codebehind without overriding the bootstrap styling, and then returning it to an editable state, all while preserving the original selected value.

Answer (score 0):

check if AutoPostBack="True"

code
 
                                    
thanx

Comment: I think, this should be a comment not an answer?

Comment: I haven't specified a value for AutoPostBack which means it will default to false.  Would changing this acheive the desired results?  If so, do I need to add it in the aspx page or do I need to set AutoPostBack to "True" in the codebehind at a different point in the code?

Comment: default AutoPostBack is false . you must change it to true . you can do that by alt of way :